# Column not found updated_at and created_at with timestamps false Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Maybe, I'm missing a little detail.
I'm trying to use create function in `RegisterController` to insert data into 2 tables. Problem is that when I separate some of the data from `$data` to insert into table personas from the `Persona` model into `$datos` and I use `var_dump()` to make sure I don't have the `created_at` and `updated_at` values in `$dato` when I try to insert with Create into personas it keeps trying to insert those values into personas table. I already have the `public timestamps='false';` in my model.

Gonna post the code here

Create function code in RegisterController

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    $datos= ['nombre' => $data['name'],'apellido' => $data['surname'],'cedula' => $data['cedula'],'email' => $data['email'],
    'telefono' =>$data['telefono'],'direccion' =>$data['direccion'],'ciudadResi' =>$data['ciudadResi'],'genero' =>$data['genero'],]; 
    var_dump($datos);

    Persona::create($datos)([
        'nombre' => $datos['nombre'],
        'apellido' => $datos['apellido'],
        'cedula' => $datos['cedula'],
        'email' => $datos['email'],
        'telefono' =>$datos['telefono'],
        'direccion' =>$datos['direccion'],
        'ciudadResi' =>$datos['ciudadResi'],
        'fechaNacimiento' =>'1998-03-05',
        'genero' =>$datos['genero'],
        'estado'=> '1',
        'idTipoPersona'=>'2'
    ]);
    
    User::create($data)([
        'name' => 'clienteUser',
        'surname' => $data['surname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'nick' => $data['nick'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'role' => 'cliente'
    ]);
}
```

Model persona code

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Persona extends Model
{

    public $timestamps ='false';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre',
        'apellido',
        'cedula',
        'email',
        'telefono',
        'direccion',
        'ciudadResi',
        'fechaNacimiento',
        'genero'
    ];
    protected $table ='personas';
    use HasFactory;
```

The rest of the code of Persona are model relationships so that souldn't be relevant. How can I make the create of Persona stop trying to add the updated_at and created_at into the personas table?

English not my main language so sorry for any mistakes or if I'm not clear enough in one part of the problem, I would gladly edit the question as necessary.

Comment: use `public $timestamps = false;` as a boolean not as a string

Comment: maybe if you use `public $timestamps ='false';` after protected `$fillable = [..];` and after of `use SoftDeletes`..